# How to load values without setTimeout?

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

Look the following example:

```
<select id="connection" onchange="load_databases_of_this_connection();"></select>
<select id="database" onchange="load_tables_of_this_database();"></select>
<select id="table" onchange="load_columns_of_this_table();"></select>
<input id="fieldcode" type="text"/>
<input id="fieldcolor" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$('#connection').change();

setTimeout("x()",2000 ); // select database and load tables

function x() {
        $('#database').val( 'main_database' );
 $('#database').change();
 setTimeout("t()",2000 );   //  select table and load columns
}


function t() {
 $('#table').val( 'payments' );    
 $('#table').change();
 setTimeout("a()",2000 ); // select columns
}

function a() {
 $('#fieldcode').val( 'code' );
 $('#fieldcolor').val( 'status' );
}

</script>
```

This code works, but I don't like it. What I want to do is to load the values subsequently, when the "change event" ends (succes or completed) then call the next, for example if I do the following example without setTimeout this not works:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#connection').change();
    $('#database').val( 'main_database' );
    $('#database').change();
    $('#table').val( 'payments' );

    $('#table').change();

    $('#fieldcode').val( 'code' );
    $('#fieldcolor').val( 'status' );
    </script>
```

I'm trying to do it with ajaxComplete but I get an infinite cycle, dure to each ajax call ends the ajaxComplete is called ... :

```
$('#database').ajaxComplete( function (e) { 
    $('#table').val( 'payments' );    
    $('#table').change();   
} );
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: As a side note here `setTimeout("x()",2000 );` should be just `setTimeout(x, 2000);` just pass a reference to the function, *never* a string (unless there's no other option).

Answer (score 1):

I solved easy...

```
$.ajax( {complete:function() {

    $('#database').val('main_database');

    $.ajax( {complete:function() {

        $('#table').val('payments');   

            $.ajax( {complete:function() { 

                $('#fieldcode').val( 'code' );
                $('#fieldcolor').val( 'status' );
            }});
    }});
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is more to your code than meets the eye, if so this should do the trick:

```
$('#connection').change(function(){
    $('#database').val('main_database');
}); 
$('#database').change(function(){
    $('#table').val('payments');    
}); 
$('#table').change(function(){
    $('#fieldcode').val( 'code' );
    $('#fieldcolor').val( 'status' );
});
```